# How to get Git to exclude a local directory from PUSH to remote, but still part of local repo

Tags: git

Using git, I would like to be able to keep a certain folder as part of my local project (feature it in branches, etc) yet I don't want this directory getting pushed up to the public git server.

The folder in question has some CLI Java stuff that the project does not need, but I would like to keep in in sync with the branch work that will go live.

Is this possible?

Comment: Reading the other answer, could you clarify if you just want one folder in your git repo which does not get tracked (no commits) or do you want a folder which you commit as usual but which is not pushed to the server?

Comment: Can you go into more detail about how the stuff in the folder you want to exclude relates to the rest of the project? Maybe it is an option to keep the stuff in a separate branch you don't push to the remote repository?

Answer (score 2):

**A very short answer is no**. Here is why: When your local git branch is pushed to a server, it's pushed as is without any exceptions. As a commit contains files, it would mess up git internally if some files would not be pushed.
This kind of selective behaviour is not supported and I guess it'll never be, as most of the time you are using git incorrectly when you need such stuff.

There are, however, many ways:

1. The first one is simply adding the stuff to the repo. You are obviously needing it and you want it to be version controlled, so from my point of view that's all that is needed to add files to git.
2. You could try git-submodules, but this would also add files to your repo. Your java cli would be another repository and your original repo would track the versions.
3. You could tell git to ignore the subfolder, than create your java-cli repository there and just the two without any interaction.

I would definitly go with 1 because when I need something for the project, then it belongs to the repo, even if it's java cli.

Answer (score 2):

## If you **don't need to track** those files at all...

... you can make git **[ignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)** them.

## If you **want to track** them locally...

... but not have them in the remote repo I can only give you some hints/ideas to thing **I never tried**, but you will probably end up having different repositories and things might **get a little nasty**.

I would **have a look at** (from *maybe ok* to *probably quite messy and a bad idea*):

- **Nested repositories**

  - [Subtrees](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging), [Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Submodules), [`git-repo`](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/), [`git-subrepo`](https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo) or similar
  - Nest repositories manually: Make git [ignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) the subfolder, set up an own repository, make sure commits somehow align
- **Remove on push**: (Drawback: You probably won't be able to properly diff as histories only match for the temporary repository. You ***could*** of course somehow also hack your diffing, making the setup even messier.)

  - Steps:

    - Before pushing clone the repository to a temporary folder
    - Remove your subfolder from the entire history inside the newly created clone (getting another repository with different commit hashes)
    - Push the newly created repository
  - Options: Trigger:

    - [`pre-push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push) [Hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)
    - Manually do the above instead of using `git push`
  - Options: Removal:

    - Tool like [BFG-Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)
    - [`git-filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#_removing_file_every_commit) by hand

---

Again: I **didn't use either of them** and **don't know their drawbacks, pitfalls etc.** but to me it seems [subtrees](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging) are by far the best solution from the above.

Most of the rest **does** seem quite messy to me but at the end of the day **the only thing that matters is what works for you**.

> [Ship lousy stuff, but ship.](http://99u.com/articles/6249/seth-godin-the-truth-about-shipping)

...be it in [Wasabi](https://blog.codinghorror.com/has-joel-spolsky-jumped-the-shark/)

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but the question is still good. You are trying to solve a deployment problem using just half of the needed tools: to acheive your goal you have to use both git AND a dependency manager in your deploy chain.

With git you can version track all your code, also the CLI Java stuff, but with DM your CLI Java stuff will be marked as a "dev" package.

Deploying in production you should exclude all "dev" packages.

In Java I think that the right tool should be Maven, in PHP there is Composer and in Javascript the most famous is NPM.

My two (late) cents

Answer (score -2):

**An even shorter answer is YES!** 
Its now a feature in github. You can exclude file types using gitignore. 
https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ 
I personally exclude the file directory called ASSETS from all my repos by adding the following to my global gitignore file: 
ASSETS/*
Example:

```
# Compiled source #
###################
*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*.o
*.so

# Packages #
############
# it's better to unpack these files and commit the raw source
# git has its own built in compression methods
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip

# Logs and databases #
######################
*.log
*.sql
*.sqlite

# OS generated files #
######################
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db

# Audio Files #
###############
*.wav
*.mp3
*.wma

# Video Files #
###############
*.wmv
*.mpg
*.mpeg
*.mp4
*.mov
*.flv
*.avi
*.ogv
*.ogg
*.webm

# Image Files #
###############
*.jpg
*.gif
*.png
*.svg
*.ico

# Folders #
###########
ASSETS/*

# Documents #
#############
*.pdf
*.doc
```

The above file on my arch linux machine is located at ~/.gitignore_global

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. Adding things to the .gitignore file will exclude them from the local project as well as the public repository.

Comment: The question is how to track them while excluding them from push, this method doesnt track them